# accent insensitive search for greek characters

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, amazon-cloudsearch

I want to search greek characters(with accent insensitive) by removing or replacing accent marks with similar characters.

Eg: when searching a greek accent word say πῬοἲὅν, we expect accent insensitive search ie need equivalent greek accent like προιον in search results.

Moreover, I am not having more knowledge on Greek characters. so only I am looking for standard rules to perform greek accent insensitive search.

Does ICUFoldingFilter solve my case? I have tried this already. Its working fine for greek accent characters. But this is not language specific... It has internalization support for all languages. Here, I am not sure whether it will break my existing language behavior in the index.

Is there any way to make ICUFoldingFilter as language specific?

Chitra

Comment: The ICUFoldingFilter is based on the rules set forward as part of the unicode standard, so they _should_ be useful for most languages. You can apply an ICUTransform with a specific ruleset if necessary instead - i.e. greek-to-latin, but I'm not sure if that solves your usecase?

Comment: so, which system is relevant for you, elastic or solr?

Comment: @Mysterion As of now, we are using Lucene

Comment: I deleted my answer since it is not actually helpful; from the data you posted below it looks like you have dirty data, probably from OCR, and in this case you probably should clean it (i.e. remove diacritics before inserting into lucene index). Cheers!

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev Chill...!!! Thank you so much for the kind response.

Comment: @MatsLindh 

ICUTransformFilter is working fine for greek characters alone. but one case it's breaking. 

Example:
I get the expected search results if I perform the search for πελάτηΣ (or) πελάτης (or) any combination of upper or lower case but if I search as πελατησ I won't get any search results.

 σ & ς are the lower forms of Σ Sigma & this case is solved in ICUFoldingFilter.

Is ICU Transliterator rule formed right? Kindly look at the below code

**TokenStream tok = new ICUTransformFilter(tok, Transliterator.getInstance("Greek; Lower; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC;"));**

Comment: @Chitra Sorry, but I have no knowledge of greek and its details, or how the ICU implementation holds up.

Comment: @MatsLindh 

cool... Thank you so much for the kind response

Answer (score 0):

@Nikolay

Already I have tried GreekAnalyzer but some cases are breaking in GreekAnalyzer too...

Eg: Indexing a Greek term **greekword:προϊόν** using GreekAnalyzer. προϊόν is indexed as **προιον** (term vector)...

If I search a term as per indexed(προϊόν) or case-sensitive accent(πΡΟΙΟν,προιον) then I will get expected results...

But it doesn't work for equivalent greek diacritics like **πῬοἲὅν,πῬὋἼὋν,πῤΟΙΟν,πΡοῐον,προἲὅν)**, here is the breakage. It doesn't return documents of προϊόν for the above search terms...

It doesn't behave as we expected. In GreekAnalyzer, there is a mismatch/discrepancy between προϊόν & πῬὋἼὋν indexed terms(term vector).

**NOTE:** But these cases are properly captured and solved in ICUFoldingFilter. As of now, our search index is working on ClassicalAnalyzer, ASCIIFoldingFilter & LowerCaseFilter and supporting Spanish, English, Chinese & Japanese characters. I have studied & examined ([testcases](https://docs.zoho.com/file/3zq5i45940531f3c947d180f2371bab66db92)) that ICUFoldingFilter is the [replacement of above two filters](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-icu/) & captured standard rules for most of the languages... 
Here I am not sure whether it will break my existing language behavior in the search index.

Kindly post your ideas/suggestions...